# I lost connection of virtual box host and guest with host-only adapter

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, virtualbox, shared-folders

Host: Windows 7
Virtual Box: 4.3.15
Guest: OSX 10.6

Setup:

```
Settings: 
Network: Host only adapter
Shared folders: c:\Share, auto-mount, make permanent

Host: ipconfig
Ethernet adapter virtualbox host-only network
ipv4 address....... 192.168.56.1
subnet mask........ 255.255.255.0

Guest: ifconfig
inet 192.168.56.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255 status active
```

I have been using this disk, on and of for some time. I have created a snapshot after installing necessary tools for development. I have been using the Share folder to transfer files to/from guest/host.

Then during a copy process I got an error about file not found...

Since then I have been unable to see my Share folder or mount it.

Even more: ping the host from guest... "Request time out".

Ping from host (windows 7) to guest... "General failure".

I have removed and re-added the share, I have reverted to the snapshot I had - nothing works.

I changed Network to NAT - and I was able to ping the host from the guest !!! (but I cannot use this setting because my Virtual Box is not allowed on the domain... and I have no way of reaching the host)

No other network options will result in a successful ping (though the host does acquire a reasonable address and sees the domain name... but i imagine for situations like bridged adapter, i may be on the wrong subnet or something). Still, it wouldn't matter if I was successful - except for troubleshooting purposes - I HAVE to use host-only adapter.

A different virtual machine, with similar settings, also fails to connect. So the problem seems about the VirtualBox itself not the individual machine...

How can I access the host share from the guest again ?

Note - pressing on the "share" at the bottom of the virtual box window, it tells me that shared folders are not supported without guest additions. Unfortunately, guest additions don't have support for osx. Yet until I got so rudely disconnected, I was able to access the shared folder !

Comment: I wonder if you can export the snapshots and reinstall virtualbox and import them?

Comment: I could maybe just create new vboxes with the existing disks if i could reinstall virtualbox... unfortunately I don't have rights to install anything :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that another virtualbox stole my host-only connection, and even upon computer shutdown it refused to give it back... (???)

Resetting the network adapters fixed it